# Executing Limit within a Function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to create a Mathematica function where f[0] = 0, f[1] = 1 and f[10] = $\infty$, ala Warp Speed from Star Trek. When I designate the following function:

```
f[x_] = Limit[90 / (10 - a) - 9, a -> x, Direction -> 1];
```

I get $f[x]=\frac{9 x}{x - 10}$ and $f[10] = ComplexInfinity$, where it executes the limit before it adds in the variable. How do I make it go the other way around, where the limit waits for the variable to come in first. Is that possible?

Comment: I think you need `:=` instead of `=`. For an explanation, see: [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487)

Comment: See nikie's comment. Thank you.